# Got status 500 on vercel for POST/PUT but OK for GET method. Locally during development all method are OK

Tags: next.js, fetch

We deploy our project on vercel...
After testing locally all are OK for database accessing (GET, POST and PUT)
I am using mongodb with mongoose for database with fetch from next.js

After deployment on vercel, still ok for GET method but get status 500 for POST and PUT

Any advise for above mentioned problem

Thank you for you all

Here mycode

```
const submitHandler = async (data) => {
    data.originatorId = user?.id
    // convert texarea to array
    const detailTask = data.detailTask.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n').split('\n')
    data.detailTask = detailTask

    const detailSHE = data.detailSHE.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n').split('\n')
    data.detailSHE = detailSHE
    try {
      dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_JOBTICKET_REQUEST' })
      const response = await fetch('/api/cmms/jobTicket/', {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      })
      console.log('CreateJobticket - submitHandler - response : ', response)
      dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_JOBTICKET_SUCCESS' })
      toast.success('Jobticket created successfully')
      router.push('/jobTicket')
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_JOBTICKET_FAIL', payload: getError(error) })
      toast.error(getError(error))
    }
}
```

It's the api-endpoint code :

```
import Jobticket from 'models/JobTicket'
import db from 'utils/db'

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
      return getHandler(req, res)
    } else if (req.method === 'POST') {
      return postHandler(req, res)
    } else {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Method not allowed' })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('handler - jobticket error: ', error)
  }
}

const postHandler = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await db.connect()
    const newJobticket = new Jobticket({
      jtNumber: req.body.jtNumber,
      tagnumber: req.body.tagnumber,
      title: req.body.title,
      respSectionId: req.body.respSectionId,
      originatorId: req.body.originatorId,
      priorityId: req.body.priorityId,
      location: req.body.location,
      statusId: req.body.statusId,
      ref: req.body.ref,
      executor: req.body.executor,
      swpNumber: '',
      detailAction: '',
      detailTask: req.body.detailTask,
      detailSHE: req.body.detailSHE,
      scheduleDate: req.body.scheduleDate,
      executeDate: '',
    })
    const jobticket = newJobticket.save()
    await db.disconnect()
    res.send({ message: 'Jobticket created successfully', jobticket })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('postHandler - jobticket error: ', error)
  }
}

const getHandler = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await db.connect()
    const jobtickets = await Jobticket.find()
    await db.disconnect()
    res.status(200).send(jobtickets)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('getHandler - jobticket error: ', error)
  }
}

export default handler
```

[It's snip from console - both for GET 7 POST/PUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuAjs.png)